# Quill - after.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, quill, parchment

Here's the Code Sandbox reproduction.

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-chihiro-9rp0d?file=/src/index.js:1285-1329

---

I've got a place in my application, where I need to insert the contents for the quill editor (a disabled one) so that a user could preview a composed Email before sending it.

[image]

There's a custom bloat called "Variable". It's used as a placeholder and gets substituted with some real data on the server (when sending an email to multiple recepients). It's represented by these blue rectangles on the pic. above.

The problem is the following. Even if I don't use any of these cutom bloats, if the whole message body looks like a single string with at least two formatting blocks in it, I get the error message specified in the header: "after.appendChild is not a function":

[image]

This is what I have on the step 3 (when editing)

[image]

And this is when previewed on the step 4 (it's inserted with the `quillInstance.setContents` method).

[image]

And the console.

So what did I do. I took the actual data object which gets inserted into that new quill editor instance via the `.setContents` method and tried to reproduce the issue in isolation (see the Code Sandbox repro link at the top).

And I found an interesting thing. It turns out that the problem resolves if you comment out the following lines:

```
Quill.register({
  "formats/Variable": Variable
});
```

So it looks like it doesn't even matter if the bloat is used or not; it only matters if the bloat is registered at all. And if it is, then the code doesn't work properly.

[image]

vs.

[image]

So, **what can I do about it**? Would appreciate any help!

Comment: I am getting a similar problem.  Did you find a solution to this?  I am using quill and made report markers extending embed.

Comment: Just played with your example.  Seems like an error occurs as soon as you have multiple bolds in a single line.   So bold than not bold then bold.  At least know the trigger but hate this limitation

Comment: @JasonWeh Hi! No, I did not find the solution sadly enough. And I'm not the part of the team working on it anymore, so I don't think there'll be a need anymore. *>  Seems like an error occurs as soon as you have multiple bolds in a single line. So bold than not bold then bold* - I remember having issues with italic text. Maybe the same happens to bold text as well, but I honestly don't remember. Good luck to you to find the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I set the tagName to `div` instead of `span` and the problem now seems to be fixed.

In your example move `Variable` to the last entry in the formats array.

Comment: In the case with my codesandox it doesn't seem to help, so I won't mark the answer the solution. But might still be helpful to others. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I have edited my answer.  Move `Variable` to last entry and your example will then work

Comment: I wish I had this a year ago... Thanks